# How do I change a variable in MainController from PartialController? (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a partial view that is using angular. How do I change a variable in the MainController from PartialController? I am not sure how to create the interdependence...

```
angularApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', '$compile', function MainController($scope, $http, $compile) { 
    $scope.myVariable = "0"; 

    //Had the following before refactoring due  to repetitive code.
    //Code now in PartialController
    //$scope.searchData = function ($event) {
    //    //code 
    //    $scope.myVariable = "1"; 
    //}

}]);

angularApp.controller('PartialController', ['$scope', '$http', '$compile', function PartialController($scope, $http, $compile) { 
    $scope.searchData = function ($event) {
        //code 
        $scope.myVariable = "1"; 
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Please add a fiddle. But probably you should try with the rootscope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sake of completeness, there are at least 3 ways:

1. **With a service as @tymeJV suggested (BEST answer)**

   ```
   app.factory('dataStore', function () {
       var dataStore = {};
       return dataStore;
   });

   app.controller('ParentCtrl', function($scope, dataStore) {
       $scope.dataStore = dataStore;
       $scope.dataStore.foo = 'bar';
   });

   app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope, dataStore) {
       dataStore.foo = 'not bar anymore';
   });
   ```
2. With an object reference on the parent scope **(A bit hackish)**

   ```
   app.controller('ParentCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.data = {
         foo: 'bar'
      };
   });

   app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.data.foo = 'not bar anymore';
   });
   ```
3. With `$parent` **(equally hackish)**

   ```
   app.controller('ParentCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.foo = 'bar';
   });

   app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.$parent.foo = 'not bar anymore';
   });
   ```

### Why are #2 and #3 hackish?

Because they create a dependency in your ChildCtrl of having it always be a child of the ParentCtrl... otherwise it will break.

### So why include #2 and #3 at all?

For a few reasons:

- Directives can have controllers, and required parent directives. Because of this, there are cases where you can "safely" use $parent or scope inheritance because you'll always know that ChildCtrl has ParentCtrl as a parent.
- Sometimes you just need to hack something together.
- As I said, for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Way better explanation, +1 for that.

Comment: good answer, although in #2, it's not really dependent on the ParentCtrl, so it's not as "hackish" as #3, at least not in the way you described it.

Comment: @NicolasMoise Well it's dependent on some parent scope having a property of data set on it already, otherwise you'll get reference errors.

Answer (score 2):

This is a prime use for a service that can be injected to controllers when you need it and pull data from it:

```
app.factory("myService", function() {
    var myVariable = null;
    return {
        get: function() {
            return myVariable;
        },
        set: function(value) {
            myVariable = value;
        }
    }
});

//Inject
angularApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', 'myService', '$compile', function MainController($scope, $http, $compile, myService) {
    myService.set(3);
});
```

Comment: +1 this answer is correct. I just added another answer to be thorough.

Answer (score 0):

tymeJV's answer is correct and is probably best practice in this case. I believe the reason it wasn't working in your example is because in Javascript, primitives (strings, numbers, booleans) are passed **by value**, whereas objects are passed **by reference**.

i.e. if you had $scope.obj.myVariable=1 in your main controller and edit $scope.obj.myVariable in your child controller, you should see the new value in both. (this is kinda #2 in blesh's answer). This is a common source of "bugs" in Angular so it's good to be aware of it.